# How to restrict search area by city in cloudmade?

Tags: geocoding, cloudmade

I use cloudmade geocoding api for search some geographic entity in a certain city, but i don't know how to restrict search area by city. I try to use structured query, for example:

**http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/api key/api/geo.location.search.2?q=[city=my_city_name]**

but, response, what i retrieved, doesn't looked like what i need.

I know about bbox, but i don't know how to determine bbox for a certain city.

I will welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set city in Cloudmade Geocoding in v3

**Note: Geocoding is only as good as the data that is, in the database. It can vary city by city or even street by street depending on the datasource.**

Cloudmade Example:

> http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/geo.location.search.2?source=OSM&q=[country=Germany]%20Berlin%20M%C3%BCllers%20Stra%C3%9Fe

Response:

```
<Response><places><Array pos="0"><addressType>street</addressType><city>~Berlin</city><country>Germany</country><featureType>Main road</featureType><position><lat>52.55108000</lat><lon>13.35101363</lon></position><state>Brandenburg</state><street>Müllerstraße</street><zip>13353</zip></Array></places><status><duration>1338</duration><procedure>geo.location.search.2</procedure><success>true</success></status></Response>
```

You can do a normal query (I have found this slower in response)
http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/geo.location.search.2?source=OSM&q=10%20Downing%20Street,%20London

Response is

```
<Response><places><Array pos="0"><addressType>housenumber</addressType><city>~London/~Westminster</city><country>United Kingdom</country><featureType>Private Road</featureType><houseNumber>10</houseNumber><position><lat>51.50327773</lat><lon>-0.12763811</lon></position><state>England</state><street>Downing Street</street><zip>SW1</zip></Array></places><status><duration>2829</duration><procedure>geo.location.search.2</procedure><success>true</success></status></Response>
```